# Plugin for Tortoise SVN get Redmine's issue list, plugin in Delphi

Tags: delphi, svn, tortoisesvn, bug-tracking, redmine

I downloaded tortoise plugin samples, but I don't know how to
implement it on Delphi.

I have successfully compile C# sample, and use it on a repository, but
my knowledge in C# for general development is poor. In other hande, I
don't know how to start creating that plugin in Delphi, but after that
I think would be easy for me.

I want to make a plugin to Redmine Issue List integration.

Something like "hello world" stuff would be great!

here some guide lines to do a new plugin using C#:
http://svn.devjavu.com/tracexplorer/trunk/ext/tortoisesvn.net/issue-tracker-plugins.txt
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=1113569

Answer (score 5):

The TSVN plugin API is COM-based. I'd start by learning how to implement a COM object in Delphi. There's [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578702216). I also found [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa113004a.htm).

If you already know how to implement COM objects in Delphi, then I apologise for being condescending. Do you have any questions specifically about the IBugTraqProvider interface? Oh, and IBugTraqProvider2 is new to TSVN 1.6 (i.e. not released yet).

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
File->New->Other...->ActiveX and select COM Object
```

You will need interface declaration. Delphi supports *.tlb directly. If there is none than you must translate *.idl to pascal interface declaration. That is easier than it sounds.
Note that interface declarations are probably somewhere in SVN trunk.

You than need to declare that your new COM object implements IBugTraqProvider interface, and implement it as you need.

When you are done, you probably need to register your new COM library with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

You can see at this page for a fonctionnal C# plugin :
http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/5420